# Update shopify app old capped for Shopify old shop's

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I developed and deployed a Shopify app on the Shopify App Store in 2019, When I launched the app I set the capped amount to be 500. 6 months back I updated the capped amount to 1000. The new capped amount is charged for the app that is installed now, but the old capped amount is still being charged in the old store. How do I update the capped amount for old stores?

I have found this [API](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2023-07/resources/recurringapplicationcharge#put-recurring-application-charges-recurring-application-charge-id-customize?recurring-application-charge%5Bcapped-amount%5D=200) in Shopify documentation, In the response of the API I got "update_capped_amount_url".
So, my question is whether new usage charges are applied after the run of this API, Or does the next time when the merchant opens the app that time first marchant have to approve new usage charges and then continue to use app? Or do I have to send this "update_capped_amount_url" URL to Merchant and then new usage charges are applied?
If you have any other way to do this please suggest us.

Answer (score 1):

On the main page of the app, you can add a banner that shows merchants the info.

For example,

**Text**: "The capped amount of the recurring charge is updated. Please upgrade."

**Button**: "Upgrade"

So when the customer clicks "Upgrade" button, you should update the capped amount of the app and let the merchant redirect to `update_capped_amount_url`.